# How do we cheat Windows Help System from Delphi Form to execute our own form?

Tags: delphi, helper

In the `TForm` we have the `HelpFile`, `HelpType` and `HelpKeyword` properties. We set the file and keyword. when we press F1 the magic comes. Everybody knows it.

But what if we want to use a data base with `keyword` and `help` fields and create a new custom form to show the help, using the `HelpKeyword` from the visual components to know which db record to show in the custom form, disabling the standard windows help system. Can we do that? **How?**

Comment: What to do when 2 answers are correct and made at the same time?

Comment: Choose whichever helps you the most (or provides you with the best solution to your problem. :-) We won't take it personally if you choose one over the other. Pick the one you feel was best.

Comment: `OnHelp` is very ad-hoc and designed to temporary intercept keywords sent to help viewer. You want to replace a help viewer completely. There is open source help viewer for older Delphi for communicating with Microsoft HTML Help, download it and use as an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either:

1. Assign a handler to the [OnHelp](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.OnHelp) event of `TApplication/Events`.
2. Write a class that implements the [`ICustomHelpViewer`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.HelpIntfs.ICustomHelpViewer) and [`IExtendedHelpViewer`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.HelpIntfs.IExtendedHelpViewer) interfaces, and then register that class for use via [`RegisterViewer()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.HelpIntfs.RegisterViewer).

Answer (score 4):

Yes. See the [`TApplication.OnHelp`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.OnHelp) event. You can easily connect it using a `TApplicationEvents` component (on the `Additional` component palette) in recent Delphi versions, or declare it yourself in older versions that don't have that component.

```
function TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Help(Command: Word; Data: NativeInt;
  var CallHelp: Boolean): Boolean;
begin
  // Stop normal help processing from being called
  CallHelp := False;

  // Command is the help command being sent.
  // Data is the context information; it varies based on Command
  // Use them to decide what your help window should do, and what
  // it should display
end;
```